# How to exclude the "More" tab where your operational layers are stored in the Flexviewer 2.2

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex

I am using Robert's awesome [TOC widget](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e2cb71d5c04d40d19e9f945ae0db7ce8).
I want to exclude the "more" tab where your operational layers show up, because they are listed in the TOC widget.

Can I do this in the config.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your talking about this More tab:
[image]
This is visible in the default configuration for the current v2.2 [Flex Viewer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/live/index.html). *

I assume you want to know how to remove it, as it maybe having sync problems with the TOC widget or perhaps you just don't need to show the layers via the More button AND the TOC widget?

I can't take credit for this, but found your answer (untested) in the [Esri forums:](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/14129-Flex-Viewer-display-LL-widget-without-quot-More...-quot-button)

Update the Map Switcher Widget's config file.
There is a visible property on the  tag which you can set to false to not show the "More" Button.

**MapSwitcherWidget.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <layerlist label="More..." visible="false">
        <!-- <excludelayer>TheLabelOfSomeLayerInMainConfig</excludelayer> -->
    </layerlist>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. What about excluding a base map tab next to the "More" button such as "Streets" "Aerial" etc?

Comment: @pdog - those base maps are also configurable via the XML files.  If you still want this answered, either re-edit your original question to include this, or ask it as a separate Q.